# Delete entire struct instance, or just part of it, rules for why gas cost differs

Tags: gas

Gas costs in Remix: `deleteStruct()` costs 25078. `deleteB()` costs 21501. `deleteAandB()` costs 21749. Interested in what the rules are around that, if anyone feels like elaborating a bit.

```
struct Foo { uint a; bool b; }
Foo foo;

function setStruct() external { foo.a = 14; foo.b = true; }

function deleteStruct() external { delete foo; }
function deleteB() external { delete foo.b; }
function deleteAandB() external { delete foo.a; delete foo.b; }
```

Comment: There isn't much to explain the compiler generates slightly different bytecode for each function. Most of the cost is from the base transaction fee 21000. The difference between deleteB (501) and deleteAandB (749) is really small. That deleteStruct is more expensive (4078) is interesting but trying to analyze that kind of things is quite boring.

Comment: It's good to know about in lots of scenarios. The one I ask for, I'd either delete the struct, and then recreate it (delete a user profile, assign them a new one), or, change variableA, but delete variableB. The latter example is cheaper. I'm using it now, primarily because it was better for a readability reason, and get the gas benefits on top of that.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? Refund rules are quite complex I won't recommend micro optimizations before the contract is more developed. I'd try to minimize the expensive operations storage and contracts interactions.